# Como faço pra colocar autoincrement

Tags: postgresql

No banco só consigo inserir  se adicionar um codigo, mas quero q seja auto increment, no banco eu uso postgre e declarei o codigo como serial

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente(codigo,nome, cpf, telefone, endereco, sexo, pagamento, modelo, ano, marca, custoconcerto) VALUES "
            + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        pst = conecta.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1,"Aqui é o autoincrement");
```

Comment: Jovem, isso nada tem a ver com Java, tampouco com gui. É alguma coisa que está errada no banco, na criação da coluna. Qual é o banco de dados que você está usando? Como você criou esta tabela?

Comment: O campo deve ser to tipo serial para isso.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_cliente
(
  codigo SERIAL,
  nome text,
  cpf text,
  telefone text,
  endereco text,
  sexo text,
  pagamento integer,
  modelo text,
  ano integer,
  marca text,
  custoconcerto float
)

Comment: essa é minha tabela, na inserção eu deixo em branco? do codigo?

Comment: Creio que se precisa no caso a chave "serial" , não "msndar" no insert.        http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm

Comment: Usando o postgree para inserir eu consigo, o problema é no java

Comment: ele pede pra mim inserir um digito para  pst.setInt(1,"Aqui é o autoincrement");, e se eu não colocar essa linha, ele avisa que ta falantando esse 1 coluna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coluna auto-increment no PostgreSQL funciona a partir do valor de padrão, não uma valor especial. Basta omiti-la:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_cliente (
    codigo SERIAL,
    nome TEXT
);

INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (nome) VALUES ('Diego');
```

Ou usar a palavra chave `DEFAULT` em vez dum valor:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (codigo, nome) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Diego');
```

As colunas que não aparecem na lista do `INSERT` ficam com os seus valores de padrão. No caso duma coluna `SERIAL` ou `BIGSERIAL`, este valor é o próximo número na sua sequência.

Em Java é igual ao no SQL: simplesmente não incluir nenhum valor para a coluna:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (nome) VALUES (?)"
// ou
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cliente (codigo, nome) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?)"
PreparedStatement pst = algo.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, oNome);
```

Há mais informações na documentação de PostgreSQL (em inglês): [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dml-insert.html), [valores de padrão](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html), [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o problema não é o comando e sim a tabela, para deixar o campo auto_increment é necessário criar uma sequência. Assim como outros SGBD.

Ficaria algo assim para criar a tabela, e quando utilizar o comando não precisa informar o campo codigo.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_cliente (codigo integer NOT NULL, "demais campos");
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_codigo
INCREMENT 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999
START 1
CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE tbl_cliente ALTER COLUMN codigo SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL("seq_codigo"::regclass);
```

Comment: A pergunta diz que o campo já é auto-increment com `SERIAL`, então não há nenhuma necessidade de criar outra sequência para um campo que já tem uma.